# How does RecyclerView handle recycling with different views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How does it handle recycling when we have heterogeneous views in a RecyclerView?
For example in the following code, we are creating 3 different types of views to be used in a recycler view.
 **Now after these views have been inflated, how does recyclerView know not to use these views for position 1 & 2 for rest of the items?**

```
private class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_1 = 1;
private static final int TYPE_2 = 2;
private static final int TYPE_3 = 3;
// more types...

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_1: inflate view_type_1
            break;
        case TYPE_2: inflate view_type_2
            break;
        case TYPE_3: inflate view_type_3
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case TYPE_1:
            break;
        case TYPE_2:
            break;
        case TYPE_3:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == 1) {
        return TYPE_1;
    } else if(position == 2) {
        return TYPE_2;
    } else 
        return TYPE_3
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RecyclerView basically keeps multiple pools of View objects, one pool for every value returned by getItemViewType.  When it needs a view for a new item, it first calls getItemViewType.  It then goes to the appropriate pool for that result (if none exists it makes a new one) and grabs a view from it.  It remembers what type each view on screen was.  When a view is cycled off the screen, its returned to the correct pool.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that recyclerView maintained multiple pools for different View types. I thought it had only 1 pool and thats why I had a hard time wondering how does it uses the correct view for binding data

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question fully. Here's an explaination of how `RecyclerView` works:

`RecyclerView.Adapter` keeps a pool of views. While possible, it will use one of the empty instances it has. When it's not possible (the pool is empty) it will create a new one. But how does this pool get empty?

When a view is attached to the `ReciclerView`, it will be removed from the pool to be added back again only when you're not displaying it -> Reason why you should reset everything in the view.

So basically RecyclerView doesn't know anything about your views. It will either use a new View, or a Recycled one taken from the pool in the adapter when possible. Then inflate what you told the view to do in the `onBindViewHolder`. If the view has some properties in it, like color or text or anything else, if you do not reset it, it will remain in the recycled view.

**EDIT**

As Gabe Sechan said, the correct view type is determined by the method `getItemViewType(int position)` that returns the correct viewtype to be inflated.

Comment: I wanted to know when recyclerView is binding data to say a 15th row, how does it know not to recycle Views of row 1 or 2 (as they are meant for those positions only).

I think Gabe Sechan's answer clears this confusion for me. Anyways, thanks for your time!

Comment: I actually didn't know the multiple pools thing, so that's a win for me too ahaha

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view has a method 
On create view in that method you are getting the same view type that you are returning from  the ( something like get viewitem type) and in on create view just implement the same checks as like get item type method and 
In on create view just pass the view to the objects of view holder as according to the
View type. Just try to take diff. View holder for different view